# Bootstrap panels side by side - can't line up panel-headings when toggling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've set my bootstrap panels side by side horizontally, like so. I've just applied "display: inline-block" to .panel class, otherwise these panel-headings all default to "block" behavior and just line up vertically, taking up four rows. I want it to stay this way, one row horizontal.

[image]

The problem occurs when I click on one of these panel-headings. I've added a "cursor: pointer" to a heading and it prompts a "collapse("toggle") on click.

[image]

Instead of the panel-body content popping out under the panel-headings, all the other panel-headings slide down and scroll out the page, so I have to manually move down the scrollbar to see other panel-headings. This really sucks. How can I just leave the panel-headings there and only let panel-body content slide down from underneath?

I haven't added much custom JavaScript except for the default Bootstrap js. 
My code below

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
           <!--COLLAPSIBLE PANELS START HERE -->
      <div id="CollapsiblePanel1" class="panel panel-default">
      <div href="#collapseOne" class="panel-heading" id="p1">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></i> TECHNOLOGY
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body" id="body1">
                   <p>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </p>

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="CollapsiblePanel2" class="panel panel-default">
      <div href="#collapseTwo" class="panel-heading" id="p2">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> EDUCATION
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
                   <p>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </p>

        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div id="CollapsiblePanel3" class="panel panel-default">
      <div href="#collapseThree" class="panel-heading" id="p3">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i> EXPERIENCE
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
                <p>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </p>

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="CollapsiblePanel4" class="panel panel-default">
      <div href="#collapseFour" class="panel-heading" id="p4">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
               <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i> VISION
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
      <p>BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH </p>
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- /bodyContent -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by making class 'panel" position: absolute. It's kind of an ugly solution but as long as the panels are not relative to each other, they won't jerk away when one opens or closes. With 'absolute' you do get that separation between the panels. Pick your poison, I guess (because I hate absolute positioning)